# What genre is Preserved Valkyria

Tags: identify-this-song, genre

For a long time I have been wondering what kind of genre songs like "Preserved Valkyria" and "Everlasting Message", etc, are.
I would call this kind of music something along the lines of fast paced modern classical insanity.
One day I came across these songs from some artist I didn't know, but I really love the songs, so digging a little deeper I found the following.

  [Preserved Valkyria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV2UOHVcp0s)
  and Everlasting Message are both made by Penoreri, but these two are the only ones of this kind he made, the rest is all jazz.

  The songs were featured in the game Sound Voltex III, where there are a few more of these kind of songs, like "For UltraPlayers".

So now having some reference material, I still couldn't find a place where there was a note of which genre these songs are categorised in and if there are more artists that make this kind of music.
Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

According to google translate's versions of  [Penoreri's website](http://penoreri.info/) ,
(apologies for the clumsy translations of the words from this website)

" SOUND VOLTEX III - GRAVITY WARS " is categorised as a Konami-like music game"

([Konami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami) is a Japanese entertainment company who are big in the video games market)

Penoreri's own profile from the same website categorises his musical range thus :

"Although adept at catchy music in pop such as Shibuya-kei and Akishibu system, jazz fusion and techno pop, such as a synthesizer lock, it is doing the music production to the genre free. Activities in regardless of genre from pop to classical."

My own take on "Preserved Valkyria" and "Everlasting Message" is that they sound like film or game music (intended to accompany some kind of visual action). Because of the slightly hard-edged sound and the use of electronics, the sound is modern, but hints at older more retro influences. The music itself has strong influences from jazz (piano part), 70s-80s progressive rock, and classical. 70s-80s progressive rock is often influenced by classical, but there are classical influences in Penoreri's music which sound slightly different from those typical of progressive rock, so I would put both as influences.

Comment: I know about konami and that penoreri mostly makes jazz/piano, but I didn't want my music to be blandly labled as "soundtrack". Thnx for your awnser though, and sorry for my late response, you got burried under emails x3